# Deserialize json using jackson to map fields to a wrapper class

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, jackson-databind

I have a JSON that looks like this

```
  {
     Name: "Jhon",
     Age: 28,
     Children:[{..},{..}]
}
```

I have created two entities Person and Children, and a wrapper Payload

```
class Payload{
  Person A;
  Children x[];
}
```

I want to do something like this

```
Payload payload = mapper.readValue(request, Payload.class);
```

The fields are not being mapped correctly, since name and age fields are at root.
A JSON like below would have worked in this scenario but I cannot change the JSON neither can I place the name and age fields inside Payload. I find out about @JsonRootName annotation but not sure how or will it work or not.

```
{
    Person: { Name: "Jhon", Age:28},
    Children: [{..},{..}]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Json To Java Class](https://json2csharp.com/json-to-pojo).

```java
// import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper; // version 2.11.1
// import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty; // version 2.11.1
/* ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
Payload payload = om.readValue(myJsonString), Payload.class); */
public class Payload {

    @JsonProperty("Name") 
    public String name;

    @JsonProperty("Age") 
    public int age;

    @JsonProperty("Children") 
    public List<Children> children;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To have `name` and `age` on top level in the jsonc-ode you might want to try putting the attributes at top level of your Payload class:

```
class Payload{
  String name;
  int age;
  Children x[];
}
```

Please let me know if this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know this would work but I need to have the name and age wrapped in another class. I need to have the Payload wrapper class which in addition to all other objects, wraps the root element as an object as well. As in my case, the Parent object.